# How to access input value from one jsp page to another jsp page using sessions?

Tags: java, html, jsp, session-variables, backend

In my login.jsp I used the following code. I created a session and intend to pass the username and email which the user will be inserting.

```
<%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1","root","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        %>
        hai
        <%
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from user3");
        HttpSession sess = request.getSession(); 
        sess.setAttribute("username","username");
        sess.setAttribute("email","email");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String username=rs.getString(1);
            String email1=rs.getString(2);
            String password1=rs.getString(3);

            if((email1.equals(email)) && (password1.equals(password)))
            {
                response.sendRedirect("book.html");
            }
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("register.html");
            }

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

%>

In another jsp page, I need to access these values i.e the username and email so that I can insert it into a database.

```
<body>


<%
HttpSession sess = request.getSession(false); 
String username=sess.getAttribute("username").toString();
String email=sess.getAttribute("email").toString();

try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1", "root", "");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();

int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into busA(username,email)values('"+username+"','"+email+"')");
out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

These are my current code, but no values are being inserted into my database as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

In the first jsp you are setting the value for the session variables as strings instead of passing the username and password variables.

So instead of :

```
sess.setAttribute("username","username");
sess.setAttribute("email","email");
```

Try

```
sess.setAttribute("username",username);
sess.setAttribute("email",email);
```

Also this issue may be relatied to not maintaning the session alive, default behavior for session in tomcat is using a cookie with the key JSESSIONID you can check with the browser dev tools if that cookie is being set and sent with the second jsp call

Inside the code you can use

```
request.getSession().getId()
```

To see if the session is the same between the 2 calls.